# Mapping http response from node to json file

Tags: json, node.js, express

I am working on a solution where the web server (node with express) will be using request package to fetch data from a web api.
The data return (if contains validation error status code), will be matched again the value and return the corresponding error message. How could it be achieve?

It would be something like this:

```
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'apiUrl'
}

var response = function (error, response, body) {
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        res.jsonp(body);
      } else {
            if (body.language == 'en') {
                // map the reponse body error status code to en.json
            } else if (body.language == 'jp')
                // map the response body  error status code to jp.json
            }
      }

request({
    options, response
})
```

Default body response for validation error

```
{
    'language': 'en',
    'error': [{ 'ErrorCode': '1000', 'ErrorCode': '1001'}]
}
```

Final body response (after processing)

```
{
    'language': 'en',
    'error': [{'ErrorMessage': 'Invalid data format', 'ErrorMessage': 'Invalid Password'}]
}
```

Resource file for different language of validation (static in server)

en.json

```
{
    '1000': 'Invalid date format',
    '1001': 'Invalid password',
    '1002': ...
    '1003': ...
    ...
    '1999': ...
}
```

jp.json

```
{
    '1000': 'japan translation',
    '1001': 'japan translation 2',
    '1002': ...
    '1003': ...
    ...
    '1999': ...
}
```

Comment: Your response is not a valid JSON, `ErrorCode` key is duplicated, do you mean `[{ 'ErrorCode': '1000' }, {'ErrorCode': '1001'}]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you see how to it.
I'm using `fs` module to open the JSON file. and I'm using `map` to convert the `errorCode` array to `errorMessage` array

```
var response = function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        res.jsonp(body);
    } else {
        // Set defaut language.
        if (!body.language.match(/en|jp|iw/)) body.language = 'en'

        // You must specify default language for security reasons.

        // Open the file, and convert to JSON object
        var j = JSON.parse(
            require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/' + body.language + '.json')
        )
        res.jsonp({
            language: body.language,

            // Convert error:[{errorCode}] array to the messages from the JSON
            error: body.error.map(function(v) {
                return j[v.ErrorCode]
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: You can replace `var j = JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/' + body.language + '.json'))` by `var j = require(__dirname + '/' + body.language + '.json')`.

Comment: Good Idea. Are you sure it's not deceprated?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, I use it all the time :) You don't even need the `.json` extension, `require` is that nice.

Comment: @Amina would this ever impost any major performance problem in the assumption that the file will be read for every request. Also, wouldn't readfilesync lock the entire web server from any other request processing?